# Python. Aiogram. Deep Linking. Как можно реализовать проверку зашел ли друг пользователя в бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот, deeplink

**В общем у меня есть бот, и я решил создать в нем некую «систему уровней».**

В боте будет три уровня, например,

- Bronze *(3 друга)*
- Silver *(5 друзей)*
- Gold *(10 друзей)*

**Чтобы поднять уровень нужно добавить несколько друзей в бота** (Чтобы друзья перешли по ссылки выданной ботам), ранее я задавал похожий вопрос и мне предложили использовать **«Deep Linking»** (Глубокие ссылки).

Почитав официальную документацию telegram  –
https://core.telegram.org/bots/features#deep-linking

Я понял, что можно **передать некоторые параметры в команду /start**
Например,

```
https://t.me/Логин_бота?start=параметр
```

Больше я ничего не нашел.

**Подскажите как мне реализовать формирование специальной ссылки и проверку перешел ли по ней друг пользователя, возможно с использованием БД для хранения количества переходов по «специальной ссылки». Реально ли это запихнуть в Inline кнопку?**

*Если есть возможности объясните все максимально подробно, я только недавно начал учить aiogram.*

Comment: Документация aiogram очень хороша с примерами, можно вот посмотреть: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/utils/deep_linking.html

Comment: Формируйте ссылку по tg id пользователя, увеличивайте значение в бд

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, в комменте к вопросу эта же ссылка и указана, я как-то упустил...

А в документации Aiogram вы читали про [Deep Linking](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/utils/deep_linking.html)

Когда кто-то переходит по ссылке вида `http://t.me/blablabot?start=blabla`
в самом боте появляется кнопка Старт, вне зависимости того, был ли ранее этот бот запущен. И при нажатии на Старт, боту передается команда /start и сам параметр, выглядит это так:

```
/start blabla
```

Что бы получить переданный параметр, используем `command.args`

Пример из документации:

```
from aiogram.utils.deep_linking import decode_payload
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, CommandObject
from aiogram.types import Message

@router.message(CommandStart(deep_link=True))
async def handler(message: Message, command: CommandObject):
    args = command.args
    payload = decode_payload(args)
    await message.answer(f"Your payload: {payload}")
```

В переменную `args` вкладываем наши `blabla` и делаем то, что нам нужно: записываем в БД тому к кому этот параметр относится, что хотим в общем

Comment: Спасибо большое!